# How to convert a Docker run command into a Swarm command?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have a setup which runs my Docker container like this.

run-docker.sh

```
docker build -t wordpress-gcloud
container=$(docker run -d wordpress-gcloud)
ipOfContainer=$(docker inspect "$container" | jq -r '.[0].NetworkSettings.IPAddress')
```

But now I have setup a Docker Swarm (1 manager + 2 workers).

How should I convert the above bash script to run the container on the swarm?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you can access your Swarm cluster via Swarm APIs, which is similar with Docker API. To access Swarm APIs, you can use `-H` parameter with docker commands. For example, if you have a swarm manager running on your local machine, and the port number is 3376, then you can get your swarm cluster info with:

```
docker -H 127.0.0.1:3376 info
```

You can also inspect the swarm cluster containers by:

```
docker -H 127.0.0.1:3376 inspect <container ID>
```

More details about communciate with Swarm cluster can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/swarm/install-manual/#/step-6-communicate-with-the-swarm

But in your case, I think that `docker build` command could be a problem. In my understanding, Swarm will find a random node from your cluster to execute this docker build process, so if the Dockerfile is not existing on the node where docker build has been executed, you will get error. My idea is to consider to build your image in a certain place, and push the image to a [image registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/), then pull and run the image in any place you want.